# WPF Tooltip Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tooltip, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am only two weeks into WPF so this is probably a trivial question.  I have a collection "CellList" which has a few properties I would like to bind to a `ToolTip` so when I hover over a label information from the current instance of `CellList` is displayed.  How do I do that?  I understand simple binding and this maybe simple binding too but I can't wrap my head around it.  Below is my XAML for the label.  Could someone explain to me how I can accomplish this.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CellList}">
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                 <Label Content=" " Height="20" Width="15" Background="{Binding Path=ExptNameBkg, Converter={StaticResource ExptNameToBrushConverter}}"                                                   BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
                  </Label>  
              </DataTemplate>                                    
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>   
       </ListBox>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<Label Content={Binding Path=Id} ToolTip={Binding Path=Name}/>
```

just try this

Comment: What would I do for a more elaborate tooltip though?  One that shows multiple properties in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825765/wpf-show-data-from-multiple-datacontexts-in-tooltip-of-itemscontrol
refer this link that will help you

Answer (score 30):

The tricky thing about `ToolTip`s is that a `ToolTip` is an object you associate with a control, and not part of the control's visual tree.  So you can't populate it the way you'd populate things in the visual tree, e.g.:

```
<TextBox.ToolTip>
   <StackPanel>
      ...put bound controls here
   </StackPanel>
</TextBox.ToolTip>
```

Instead, what you have to do is create a specific instance of a ToolTip, and assign it a style that sets its `DataContext` (very important; that's how you can bind to the properties of the data source of its "placement target," i.e. the control that's displaying the tooltip) and its `Template`.  Then put the visual tree of the `ToolTip`, including bindings, into the template.  Finally, reference the `ToolTip` in your control.

So, here's a `TextBox` whose `Binding` does validation:

```
<TextBox ToolTip="{StaticResource ErrorToolTip}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="SourceProperty">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
               <DataErrorValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

It uses this `ToolTip`:

```
<ToolTip x:Key="ErrorToolTip" Style="{StaticResource ErrorToolTipStyle}"/>
```

And the `ToolTip` uses this style, which gets its content from the `ValidationError` property of the `TextBox`'s binding source:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorToolTipStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Border
                    Name="Border" 
                    BorderThickness="1" 
                    BorderBrush="LightGray">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Background="Firebrick" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="4">Validation error</Label>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding ValidationError}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'm not certain of this, but I think that the only part of the above that actually has to be set in the style is the `DataTrigger` setting the `DataContext`; I think most everything else could just be explicitly set in the `ToolTip`'s visual tree.  But I'm probably not thinking of something important.

Comment: tip: whether you're putting this into local resources (UserControl.Resources) or a global dictionary make sure you define the <Style> BEFORE the <Tooltip>. resources don't allow for forward references. if not you'll get an unresolvable reference which may not immediately be obvious if you've copied the code in the order shown above.

Comment: You can also use dynamic references instead of static references, but yes, generally you want to define styles before you use them.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks! A style isn't even required, you can just apply the binding to the `DataContext` property directly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a kaxaml-ready example that includes a tooltip that is a little more elaborate than just text:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="CharacterData">
      <x:XData>
        <Data xmlns="">
          <Character First="Bart" Last="Simpson" Background="LightGreen" />
          <Character First="Homer" Last="Simpson" Background="LightBlue" />
          <Character First="Lisa" Last="Simpson" Background="Pink" />
          <Character First="Maggie" Last="Simpson" Background="Yellow" />
          <Character First="Marge" Last="Simpson" Background="PapayaWhip" />
        </Data>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
    <ToolTip x:Key="ElaborateToolTip">
      <Grid Margin="5">
        <Rectangle RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" Fill="{Binding XPath=@Background}" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@First}" Margin="0,0,6,0" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Last}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </ToolTip>
  </Page.Resources>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CharacterData}, XPath=Data/Character}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource ElaborateToolTip}" />
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@First}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Page>
```