# How to Bind ListBox.Tooltip to DataTable programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

How to bind **ListBox's** **ToolTip** to DataTable?

There is only `ListBox.ItemsSource`, but there is not `ListBox.ToolTip.ItemsSource`.

Comment: let me get it , u want to add tooltip on listbox items ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToolTip` is a `ContentControl`, not a `ItemsControl`. That means that it could contain only single element and not a collection.

To show multiple items in the `ToolTip` you need to place some `ItemsControl` (`ListBox`, for example) into the `TabControl` and then use its `ItemsSource` property.

```
ListBox list = new ListBox();
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
ListBox tooltipList = new ListBox();

list.ToolTip = tooltip;
tooltip.Content = tooltipList;
tooltipList.ItemsSource = /*your source*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following:

[WPF Show data from multiple DataContexts in ToolTip of ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825765/wpf-show-data-from-multiple-datacontexts-in-tooltip-of-itemscontrol)

The link above contains a more advanced scenario, however it could be used to extract the code required for your implementation.

Hope it helps!